# How to get the access token in google app engine endpoints for User object?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, oauth-2.0, google-api, access-token

I am able to get the User Google information such as email and nick name . But I want to retrieve the user profile image from the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile`

To access that I need to call this
`https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo?alt=json&access_token=XXX`

This will return back the Json data containing the link to profile picture.
Sample response for above request with access_token

```
{
  "id": "123",
  "name": "Admin User",
  "given_name": "Admin",
  "family_name": "User",
  "link": "https://plus.google.com/XYZ",
  "picture": "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/XYX/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg",
  "locale": "en"
}
```

How do I get the access token in Java?

My code is pasted below:

```
package com.example.myapplication.backend;

import com.google.api.server.spi.config.Api;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiMethod;
import com.google.api.server.spi.config.ApiNamespace;
import com.google.appengine.api.oauth.OAuthRequestException;
import com.google.appengine.api.users.User;

import java.io.IOException;

/** An endpoint class we are exposing */
@Api(
  name = "myApi",
  version = "v1",

        scopes = { Constants.EMAIL_SCOPE2 },
        clientIds = { Constants.WEB_CLIENT_ID, Constants.ANDROID_CLIENT_ID,
                Constants.API_EXPLORER_CLIENT_ID},
        audiences = {Constants.ANDROID_AUDIENCE},


  namespace = @ApiNamespace(
    ownerDomain = "backend.myapplication.Ajay.example.com",
    ownerName = "backend.myapplication.Ajay.example.com",
    packagePath=""
  )
)
public class MyEndpoint {

    /** A simple endpoint method that takes a name and says Hi back */
    @ApiMethod(name = "sayHi")
    public MyBean sayHi( User user) throws OAuthRequestException, IOException
     {
        MyBean response = new MyBean();
         response.setData(user.getEmail() + "  nick name->" + user.getNickname() + "user id " + user.getUserId() + "-->" +
                 user.toString() + "getAuthDomain--->" + user.getAuthDomain().toString()+" token");
        return response;
    }


}
```

Comment: we can't do it on server side unless, we have a refresh token of the user. Instead do this on client side

Answer (score 0):

You can't , user object in appengine is an convenience and quick way to get the currently authenticated user, this is maintained as Principle in appengine.

If you want to obtain an access token, you must user the [Google OAuth2](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2), and then you will be getting access token, if the user approves.